# While printing store_id field value differs at both frontend and backend

Tags: magento-1.7

I have printed the value for Product in both frontend and admin but value for store_id differs. In frontend it gives 1 and at backend it gives 0. Any specific reason why?

I have used this code also

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

**Frontend it gives 1 and at backend it gives 0.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its display store_id for frontend and adminpanel.

Both store have different store_id so its display differnt.

```
For Backend/Adminpanel its 0 and Default store have store_id is 1.
```

You can check differnt store id in **`core_store`** database table.

Comment: How to get default store id in admin?

Comment: its 1 by default and i have update my answer plz check it